# Faces mixed up after baking

Tags: texture-baking

[image]

wrap my head with this problem
every time when trying to bake my models with lighting, blender mixing up the light between different faces and it looks completely weird.
please help me to find where is the issue

Comment: What baking settings have you used? If you bake the diffuse color with direct and indirect lights and the world has the default grey light then this can be the result.

Comment: Yes, this is the issue. without light everything is fine. But i need lighting on the model. When i changed automatic UV on lighting map, the light become normal but UV there is comp[letely crazy,

Comment: The default world color is dark grey. Maybe set it to white so you have more light in your scene?